# How to reusing the SnowflakeOperator for multiple .sql files

Tags: airflow, snowflake-connector

sf_task_1 = SnowflakeOperator(task_id="sf_task_1",dag=my_dag,sql="/sql/abc.sql",)
how we can reuse SnowflakeOperator for multiple .sql files in airflow

Comment: How would you expect to determin the order of execution for the files?

Comment: sf_task_1 = SnowflakeOperator(task_id="sf_task_1",dag=my_dag,sql="/sql/abc.sql",)